# How can i get ubuntu on my Nokia N 900?

Tags: nokia

Maemo 5 is not longer working on this device - Nokia is gone and also every other help.
So i think i`ll try ubuntu because it is working on my notebook superious.
But how can i get it into my device?

Comment: You can't install Ubuntu on that phone, 600 MHz Cortex-A8, PowerVR SGX530 and 256mb of RAM? It is no where near the specs for Ubuntu phone.

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/)